# Dynamically initialize a class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, metaprogramming

I'm trying to tidy up some routes in an Express application, and I'd like to be able to define all my routes in an object, as well as the controller they belong to, the services to inject into the controller (this could be any number of services) to and a method for each route. Here's what I have so far:

```js
// controllers/premisesController.ts
export default class PremisesController {
  constructor(
    private readonly premisesService: PremisesService,
    private readonly bookingService: BookingService
  ) {}

  new() {}

  create() {}

  confirm() {}
}

// controllers/bookingsController.ts
export default class BookingsController {
  constructor(private readonly bookingService: BookingService) {}

  new() {}

  create() {}
}

// services/bookingService.ts

export default class BookingService {}

// services/premisesService.ts

export default class PremisesService {}

// index.ts

import { RequestHandler, Router } from "express";

import * as controllers from "./controllers";
import { services } from "./services";

type ControllerModule = typeof import("./controllers");
type Controllers = ControllerModule[keyof ControllerModule];

interface RouteDefs {
  [k: string]: {
    controller: Controllers;
    services: Array<string>;
    routes: {
      [k: string]: {
        path: string;
        method: "post" | "get";
      };
    };
  };
}

const routeDefs: RouteDefs = {
  premises: {
    controller: controllers.PremisesController,
    services: ["premisesService", "bookingService"],
    routes: {
      index: { path: "/premises", method: "get" },
      show: { path: "/premises/:id", method: "get" }
    }
  },
  bookings: {
    controller: controllers.BookingsController,
    services: ["bookingService"],
    routes: {
      new: { path: "/premises/:premisesId/bookings/new", method: "get" },
      create: { path: "/premises/:premisesId/bookings", method: "post" },
      confirm: {
        path: "/premises/:premisesId/bookings/:bookingId/confirmation",
        method: "get"
      }
    }
  }
};

const router = Router();

const methods = {
  get: (path: string | string[], handler: RequestHandler) =>
    router.get(path, handler),
  post: (path: string | string[], handler: RequestHandler) =>
    router.post(path, handler)
};

Object.entries(routeDefs).forEach(([_k, v]) => {
  const ControllerName = v.controller;
  type Args = ConstructorParameters<typeof ControllerName>;

  const servicesForController = v.services.map(
    (service) => services[service]
  ) as Args;

  const Controller = new ControllerName(...servicesForController);

  Object.entries(v.routes).forEach(([action, def]) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(
      `Defining ${def.method.toUpperCase()} ${def.path} => ${
        Controller.constructor.name
      }#${action}`
    );

    methods[def.method](def.path, Controller[action]());
  });
});
```

You can see a running minimal reproducable example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-meadow-27pyof?file=/src/index.ts

However, when I try and initialize the controller with the services on this line:

```js
const Controller = new ControllerName(...servicesForController)
```

I get the error:

```js
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
```

I feel like a solution is almost in sight, but I've hit a brick wall. Any ideas?

Comment: We don't have your controller classes. But yeah it's exactly what TypeScript says. Your controller constructors don't take rest parameters and your `servicesForController` variable isn't a tuple so TypeScript can't type check this call.

Comment: @kelly I've updated my question with some example controllers

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I've updated the code and posted a link to codesandbox.io

Comment: When I look at that codesandbox.io link I see three errors about module imports, and not the error mentioned in your question.  In order for this to be a [mre] I should immediately see the issue when looking.  Ideally you would provide this in a single self-contained snippet of code that wouldn't require a multi-file environment or third party imports (unless your question depends on third party packages in which case you should tag the question as such), but a properly configured web IDE project that immediately shows the issue is the next best thing.  Right now though ‍♂️

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I dashed it out in a bit of a rush. Have fixed now.